# Cloudflare DNS + Netlify CDN // HTTPS not working

Tags: ssl, dns, cdn, cloudflare, netlify

I'd like to configure a static website with the following set up.

- **DNS** : Cloudflare
- **CDN** : Netlify

For a number of reason I would prefer to keep the DNS on Cloudflare, while using the Netlify CDN, which is working surprisingly well for me.

In order to do this, I set a CNAME entry on Cloudflare's DNS pointing to the Netlify sitename.netlify.com (Cloudflare supports Flatten CNAME at root) and deactivated the CDN in the Cloudfare DNS Control Panel (with the Grey cloud instead of the Orange cloud).

While working perfectly with an unsecured connection, I immediately experienced problems with the HTTPS. When trying to browse `https://myparticulardomain.example` I get an

> ERROR 3019: HTTPS CERTIFICATE COULD NOT BE VALIDATED

I am trying to follow the procedure on Cloudflare where I generate an Origin TSL Certificate and then try to set up a custom SSL certificate on Netlify.

From Netlify Docs:

> To install a certificate, you’ll need:
>
> -the certificate itself, in X.509 PEM format (usually a .crt file)
>
> -the private key you used to request the certificate
>
> **-a chain of intermediary certificates from your Certificate Authority (CA)**

The first two items are fine, I am not sure what is the 3rd one and where to find it on Cloudflare's dashboard. Am I following the right path?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Cloudflare to handle the certificate for you, first give a try setting the Flexible option:[image]

If that works then you could also give a try the options **Full** of **Full (strict)**, check this post for more details: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-

Answer (score 0):

You should never select "Flexible" in Cloudflare.  **Ever**.  It *requires your origin to be publicly exposed* on port 80 with *absolutely no security*.  Don't even do this for static assets.

Netlify lets you "Install a custom certificate" for each domain- requiring a certificate, a key, and an intermediate chain certificate.

Cloudflare lets you create an origin certificate and private key, and you use Cloudflare's Origin CA as the Intermediate Certificate.

Again, **never** use "Flexible".  Take the time to learn how to set up TLS properly, pretty much every provider has a mechanism, and installing a Cloudflare certificate is among the easiest.

Comment: It's a static website. Not every website needs encryption. There are people using cloudflare only for it's CDN and use ssl only to be able to use the server push feature.

Comment: @HowAboutTau First and last paragraphs may be opinions.  A citation would help.  Otherwise consider removing.  Second paragraph could be quoted from the question, or removed.  Third paragraph is a well written answer.  The post may benefit from a URL about the answer.  (Congrats on your first answer.  Keep 'em coming.)

Comment: @howabouttau doesn't  method suggested by you will require manually updating certificates before expiry ?

Comment: "Flexible is not recommended if your website contains sensitive information. Use Flexible only as a last resort if you are unable to setup SSL at your origin web server." from https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-#h_4e0d1a7c-eb71-4204-9e22-9d3ef9ef7fef